# Simple server-push broadcast flow with Akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am struggling to implement a - rather simple - Akka flow.
Here is what I think I need:

[image: akka-flow]

I have a single server and n clients and want to be able to react to external events by broadcasting messages (JSON) to the clients. The clients can register/deregister at any time.

So for example:

- 1 client is registered
- server throws an event ("Hello World!")
- server broadcasts a "Hello World!" to all clients (one client)
- a new client opens a websocket connection
- server throws another event ("Hello Akka!")
- server broadcasts a "Hello Akka!" to all clients (two clients)

Here is what I have so far:

```scala
def route: Route = {
   val register = path("register") {
     // registration point for the clients
     handleWebSocketMessages(serverPushFlow)
   }
}

// ...

def broadcast(msg: String): Unit = {
  // use the previously created flow to send messages to all clients
  // ???
}

// my broadcast sink to send messages to the clients
val broadcastSink: Sink[String, Source[String, NotUsed]] = BroadcastHub.sink[String]

// a source that emmits simple strings
val simpleMsgSource = Source(Nil: List[String])

def serverPushFlow = {
  Flow[Message].mapAsync(1) {
    case TextMessage.Strict(text) =>       Future.successful(text)
    case streamed: TextMessage.Streamed => streamed.textStream.runFold("")(_ ++ _)
  }
  .via(Flow.fromSinkAndSource(broadcastSink, simpleMsgSource))
  .map[Message](string => TextMessage(string))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use a broadcastHub, you have to define two flows. One that runs your websocket `TextMessage` to the `broadcastHub`. You have to run it, it produces a Source that you connect to each client.

Here it is this concept described in simple runnable app.

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{BroadcastHub, Sink, Source}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object BroadcastSink extends App {

  private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("logger")

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val broadcastSink: Sink[String, Source[String, NotUsed]] =
    BroadcastHub.sink[String]

  val simpleMsgSource = Source.tick(500.milli, 500.milli, "Single Message")

  val sourceForClients: Source[String, NotUsed] = simpleMsgSource.runWith(broadcastSink)

  sourceForClients.to(Sink.foreach(t => logger.info(s"Client 1: $t"))).run()
  Thread.sleep(1000)

  sourceForClients.to(Sink.foreach(t => logger.info(s"Client 2: $t"))).run()
  Thread.sleep(1000)

  sourceForClients.to(Sink.foreach(t => logger.info(s"Client 3: $t"))).run()
  Thread.sleep(1000)

  sourceForClients.to(Sink.foreach(t => logger.info(s"Client 4: $t"))).run()
  Thread.sleep(1000)

  actorSystem.terminate()
}
```

Prints

```
10:52:01.774 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:02.273 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:02.273 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:02.773 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:02.773 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:03.272 Client 3: Single Message
10:52:03.272 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:03.272 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:03.772 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:03.772 Client 3: Single Message
10:52:03.773 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:04.272 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:04.272 Client 4: Single Message
10:52:04.272 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:04.273 Client 3: Single Message
10:52:04.772 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:04.772 Client 2: Single Message
10:52:04.772 Client 3: Single Message
10:52:04.772 Client 4: Single Message
10:52:05.271 Client 4: Single Message
10:52:05.271 Client 1: Single Message
10:52:05.271 Client 3: Single Message
10:52:05.272 Client 2: Single Message
```

If clients are known in advance, you don't need BrodacastHub and you can use `alsoTo` method:

```
  def webSocketHandler(clients: List[Sink[Message, NotUsed]]): Flow[Message, Message, Any] = {
    val flow = Flow[Message]
    clients.foldLeft(flow) {case (fl, client) =>
      fl.alsoTo(client)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand two things here: 
1. How do you send something else than "Single Message" with this? and 2. How do you even connect the clients via the routing?

Comment: Updated the answer. 1. It's just an example., the source of messages comes from akka http. 2. See update, in this case BrodacastHub is not needed

Comment: "It's just an example., the source of messages comes from akka http"
But in my use-case the message does not com from akka-http. How do I get an event to trigger a broadcast (server-push)?

Comment: I updated my question because I think it caused some misunderstandings.